# Infrastructure for running Spark

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, kaggle

I'm participating in a Kaggle competition with 4 other people. We all met in a MOOC by edx.org.

Although we can code using the Apache Spark engine, we don't know how to set up a cluster and install the necessary software to run spark on it.

Ideally, we're looking for a free platform that allows us to focus on the programming.

Do you know any platform that is easy to use and, ideally, free? If there isn't one, can you tell us how to set up the necessary infrastructure to participate in the challenge?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that hard to start a [standalone cluster](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) on Linux or OS X using the bundled scripts, which could be sufficient if you can work with one node, or each contribute your development computers to a cluster (on the same LAN).

When you need to scale, [AWS EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/) is pretty simple.

For a little more money, [Databricks](https://databricks.com/) offers Spark as a managed service. Which means you really don't have to think too much about running the cluster.

Comment: Since we all live in different locations, running a cluster on the same LAN is not an option.

Comment: Since we all live in different locations, running a cluster on the same LAN is not an option. The size of the raw data file (.csv) is roughly 80mb. Can I run this locally or will it take forever to perform a task?

Comment: While you are developing you may not need to use all your data. 80MB is not that much though. Is Spark the best choice? Have you considered R or Python for your first competition?